# Certificate chain errors on mobile with Commodo

Tags: https, security-certificate

A number of websites I administer use SSL certificates supplied by Comodo. After supplying the complete certificate chain in the certificate file, SSL Labs reports an A-Grade for the site with the "full trust chain" provided. Nevertheless, the certificate chain errors persist for mobile browsers only. 
 The complete error text is:

"This certificate isn't from a trusted authority".

I am now getting this error on a number of different sites and a number of different certificates. The only commonality is that all of them use Comodo as a root CA. Is this coincidence?

Comment: Sharing the site URL in question will go along way with the community.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when connecting to an SSL protected government portal I have access to from my mobile device when the server was protected by Comodo. Turns out some mobile devices don't have the Comodo root CA installed from the factory and need to go through an update to get the Root CA installed. Was a predominant issue with Android devices but I did hear of the same thing happening with some older iOS devices and even older blackberries. There is a page on the Comodo site where you can download the Root CA's to your device but this is mainly for computers which make it easy to add root CA's whereas most mobile devices dont support adding new root CA's except through a system update from the manufacturer.